# Where can I ask, if I can ask at all, the following question (search for an e-commerce software)

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions

I opened [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/399441/commercial-webshop-with-supported-xls-or-csv-import-features) on SU, about looking for a self-hosted E-commerce software with advanced importing and exporting capabilites.

Soon after, [the question](https://superuser.com/questions/399441/commercial-webshop-with-supported-xls-or-csv-import-features) got closed.
**Can I ask such a question? If yes, which is the most appropriate site to do it?**

The question can be understood from two point of views. First is a shopping advice, which the FAQ doesn't tolerate (when it comes to hardware), and it's okay, no prob. The other one is ... searching for a software. As I mentioned in the comment (at SU), I tried open-source engines, but they didn't have any kind of import/export. I also bought a module for an open-source E-commerce CMS, but at the end, it couldn't import correctly.

Comment: It's out in the wild! http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27131/self-hosted-e-commerce-software-preferably-php-with-advanced-import-capabiliti

Comment: I had asked webmasters mods if they wanted the question migrated, but didn't hear from them, so I closed it as OT instead of migrating it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [slhck](https://meta.superuser.com/users/48078/slhck) answered it in the comments fairly well:

> This is **essentially a shopping recommendation** and hosted apps like
>   Joomla, Drupal, etc. are off-topic here as far as I'm concerned. Maybe
>   Webmasters? I'm sure there are plenty of commercial webshop solutions
>   available – have you looked into those? Magento comes to mind

Basically, there is no direct answer to the question, and could poll lots of opinions and advertisement. Unless you're talking about how to setup the software, we can't really help you with your own website's management. There really isn't anywhere to ask this question, and you will have to do research yourself (or get a posse to help out)

Comment: I tried to do a research on my own (after the linked in wiki entry), but it's really hard. That comparison chart is really outdated, and the comparison tables are cluttered. I know they won't give me 100% correct answer which I can just buy then or install. But this is what happens with every software. "Which software let's me remove duplicate files." For example. Let's say it's a commercial software (which does this), but it does it really well. It gets upvoted, it gets accepted.

Comment: That's why I made the question, and asking if it's feasible for any Exchange site. I will remove the "no free" part of course, but they won't fit the bill. I tried them all recently, and just no. The addons are horrible, full of security holes and bugs. And once you pay, you won't ever see the addon writer again. No way to contact him. Hiring a programmer just for this? It would cost more than a whole E-commerce app.

Comment: @Shiki But its not computer software, its web stuff. I suppose it might be viable on webmasters, you should ask them in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/ just @ one of their moderators. Or perhaps webapps, ask them